# using order by in merged select query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

the below shown is my mysql query

```
SELECT mail FROM table2 WHERE wid IN
(SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM table1 
WHERE time_stamp>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND status<>200 
ORDER BY time_stamp ASC)
LIMIT 2");
```

this fetches 2 entries always that works fine.but its not ordered in ascending. the query always pick rows starting from first row without doing order by(I know limit will start only from first row). I need to fetch the `ID` from table 1 after ordering the time_stamp in ascending order.

problem:-i need to sort table 1 in ascending order with respect to the time_stamp column in the table1. and then select the first 2 entries from that. and find its email id from table2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding `ORDER BY time_stamp ASC` for subquery.

For getting record ordered you need to add `ORDER BY wid ASC` outside of `IN` clause.

**OR**

use the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` OR `INNER JOIN` for getting record sorted according to `timestamp`.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT
    mail
FROM
    table2
INNER JOIN
    table1 ON table2.wid = table1.id
WHERE
    table1.time_stamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
AND
    table1.status<>200
ORDER BY
    table1.time_stamp ASC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: "order by wid ASC" ?? sorry i didn't get u sir.. i need to sort 'table1' according to the time_stamp column for that where i should add order by time_stamp asc??

Comment: it worked..but the join brings duplicate rows also.. can u plz tell me how can i use distinct with inner join??

Comment: @user007 yes you can use `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: is thr any rule about the position at which group by should wrote. i mean before orderby or something like that. i give "group by table1.Id" before order by table1.time_stamp ASC. but it takes the first row only always. :(

Comment: @user007 yes that is what group by meant for....group by always return first matched records,